# How to unpack nested data into a function?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, destructuring

I want to pull the `income` property from an object into a function var:

```
    let obj1 = {
        x: {
            income: 200,
            sex: 'male'
        },
        y: 'name1'
    };

    function informUserData({
     //what to put here ?
    }){
        return income;
    }
    console.log(informUserData(obj1));// it should be 200
```

I tried this:

```js
function informUserData({
     x{
         income
     }
    }){
        return income;
    }
    console.log(informUserData(obj1));
```

Then, I tried this, just to check how to unpack a no-nested property value.

```js
    let obj1 = {
        x: {
            income: 200,
            sex: 'male'
        },
        y: 'name1'
    };

    function informUserData({
     y
    }){
        return y
    }
    console.log(informUserData(obj1)); // name1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that the problem was a syntax problem Instead of `property property` I needed `property : property`. So:

```
    let obj1 = {
        x: {
            income: 200,
            sex: 'male'
        },
        y: 'name1'
    };

    function informUserData({
     x: {income}
    }){
        return income
    }
    console.log(informUserData(obj1))
```